# Javascript string to Integer/String combo

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have a problem. I'm trying to launch a gallery slider with following function :

```
var urlPhotoID = window.location.href.split("?foto=")[1];
var _lr.cfg.currentArticle.id = 236888;
var articleId = 'window.g' + _lr.cfg.currentArticle.id;
console.info(articleId); // Logs "window.g236888"

gallery.init(articleId,urlPhotoID);
```

But it won't work, cause articleId is a string, and I need an object/integer.

The following works great :

```
gallery.init(window.g236888,urlPhotoID);
```

How can I parse my articleId var to work with my gallery init?

Thanks!

Comment: looking for the dupe, use bracket notation.... `window['g' + _lr.cfg.currentArticle.id];`

Comment: @epascarello  this makes the 'g236888' a property of window. what is the value of the property

Comment: because that is what it is....

Comment: Yeah it should work

Answer (score 1):

Use the bracket notation:

```
var urlPhotoID = window.location.href.split("?foto=")[1];
var _lr.cfg.currentArticle.id = 236888;
var articleId = 'g' + _lr.cfg.currentArticle.id;
console.info(articleId); // Logs "window.g236888"

gallery.init(window[articleId],urlPhotoID);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function :

```
var articleId = eval('window.g' + _lr.cfg.currentArticle.id);
```

Comment: Please try it before you post

Comment: @JinsPeter well it does, `var foo = 'here I am'; console.log(eval('foo')); // prints 'here I am'`

Comment: @Karolis Great, please consider accepting my answer then